# Remove freight method and shipping title from checkout cart page

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

Is it possible to hide the text for (free) shipping method and shipping title on checkout cart, I dont mind if doesnt show anywhere else on the frontend neither. The freight is free, thats all the customer needs to know.

Sorry, somehow I had typed a misleading title. Sorry. I fixed it now.

---

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

Please overide your `checkout_cart_index.xml` in your theme.check line no near about 55. We have added "`componentDisabled`" code. By this code etimate shipping and tax box remove.

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">

                    <!-- My custom code: -->
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>

                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>


To remove the heading as well, override the template checkout/cart/shipping.phtml and comment/remove the following:

<div class="title" data-role="title">
    <strong id="block-shipping-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQuote()->isVirtual() ? __('Estimate Tax') : __('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Abhinav, I think you only read the title of my question which was very misleading. I think I took it from another question I asked. I have edited the title now. Sorry!